# Do you need to call Flush to a FileStream if you need to read its data after writing to it from the same stream?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, io, filestream

```
using Stream someOtherData = GetMeSomeData();
using FileStream fs = File.Create("Hello-world!");
someOtherData.CopyTo(fs);
fs.Flush(); // Is this needed?
fs.Position = 0;
ReadDataInStream(fs); // Reads the data in the stream by using Stream.Read().
```

Comment: Depends. The contents of `someOtherData` might not have been fully written to disk if you don't flush. However, it will still be available to someone reading `fs`. Do you care if the data is all flushed to disk?

Comment: @canton7 no, as long as `ReadDataInStream(fs)` has no trouble reading all the data in the stream.

Comment: @canton7 I thought that reading from the stream first reads the internal buffer (similar to StreamReader's implmenetation) and then gets new data from the OS? That's why you ought to call `StreamReader.DiscardBufferedData()` before you start re-reading from the same `StreamReader` after resetting its position, or are the implementation details different here for `FileStream`?

Comment: Actually, reading the source, setting the Position flushes the write buffer anyway, so it's moot

Comment: @canton7 You are right if it uses [Net5CompatFileStreamStrategy](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Net5CompatFileStreamStrategy.Unix.cs,551)! But otherwise, if the strategy used is [OSFileStreamStrategy](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/OSFileStreamStrategy.cs,110), I don't see that behavior present there? I believe only those 2 strategies are being used, the rest are wrappers for existing ones.

Comment: @canton7 Actually my runtime seems to be using `SyncWindowsFileStreamStrategy`, and sadly source.dot.net has no references to that, nor can I find it using google.

Comment: Note that some of the underlying details of how the file position is handled are changed for .net 6: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/file-io-improvements-in-dotnet-6/

Comment: I was assuming you'd be using a `BufferedFileStreamStrategy`, from [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/FileStreamHelpers.cs,16) and [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/FileStreamHelpers.cs,66c3c193d56dcbc1), so that's the one I inspected

Comment: `SyncWindowsFileStreamStrategy` [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b683032718a1e76ca93147fc4a273e250ef65525/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/SyncWindowsFileStreamStrategy.cs). That one doesn't do any in-memory buffering at all -- that's all handled by the `BufferedFileStreamStrategy` which wraps it, I think

Comment: @canton7 you're right. Yes, my mistake - the runtime uses `BufferedFileStreamStrategy` which wraps a `SyncWindowsFileStreamStrategy`, so tldr: me setting the position won't clear the buffers inside, as it just calls `OSFileStreamStrategy.Write()` and then `OSFileStreamStrategy.Position = value`

Comment: @SpiritBob You're missing the point. The `BufferedFileStreamStrategy.Position` setter calls `FlushWrite`, [see here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs,73). Setting the stream's position flushes the write buffer. It won't necessary flush things like the OS or disk cache, but it will flush the buffer held internally inside `FileStream`

Comment: @canton7 you're right yet again! Indeed, it seems whatever strategy `FileStream` ends up using, it will either be a `Net5CompatFileStrategy` which [has its own buffering logic](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Net5CompatFileStreamStrategy.Unix.cs,556) or an OS specific class, which might use buffering if the caller has not specified a buffer size of 0 (or 1 if using `Net5CompatFileStreamStrategy`) in which case - there's no need of calling `Stream.Flush()` as setting the position will also clean the buffer (similar to `Net5CompatFileStreamStrategy`). Is all of the above correct?

Comment: That's my understanding: if there's buffering, setting `Position` flushes the write buffer. That doesn't necessarily mean the data is flushed to disk, but it does mean that reading from the stream will read the data you previously wrote to the stream